# Get many rows from a list of IDs

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using C# and SQL Server.  I have a list of IDs for documents which corresponds to the primary key for a table in SQL Server that has a row for each document and the row contains (among other things) the ID and the document for that ID.  I want to get the document in the row for each of the IDs.  Currently, I execute a query for each ID, but since there are 10,000s of them, this runs a ton of queries and takes a very long time.  It ends up being faster to simply load everything from the table into memory and then filter by the ids I have, but that seems inefficient and won't scale over time.  If that doesn't make sense, hopefully the following code that takes a long time to run shows what I'm trying to do.

```
    private static Dictionary<Guid, string> foo(IEnumerable<Guid> guids, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, conn))
        {
            command.CommandText = "select document from Documents where id = @id";
            SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
            command.Parameters.Add(idParam);
            command.Prepare();

            var documents = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
            foreach (var guid in guids)
            {
                idParam.Value = guid;
                object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    documents[guid] = (string)obj;
                }
            }
            return documents;
        }
    }
```

I could programmatically construct query strings to use where clause like this: ".... where id in (ID1, ID2, ID3, ..., ID100)" to get 100 documents at a time or something like that, but this feels janky and it seems to me like there's got to be a better way.

I'm sure I'm not the only one to run into this.  Is there an accepted way to go about this?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but isn't there a limit to the size of a query I can send?  the ids are guids which end up being 36 bytes each.  So if I have 20,000 ids, thats a query over 72,000 bytes long.  And this may grow to hundreds of thousands.  Is there no limit on the size of a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) with no limits in amount of guids

In the code you will create SqlParameter with all Id's you need to

First you need create type of parameter in the sql server

```
CREATE TYPE IdTableType AS TABLE   
( 
    Id uniqueidentifier 
);
```

Then in the code

```
private static Dictionary<Guid, string> foo(IEnumerable<Guid> guids, SqlConnection conn)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, conn))
    {
        // use parameter as normal table in the query
        command.CommandText = 
            "select document from Documents d inner join @AllIds a ON d.id = a.Id";

        // DataTable is used for Table-Valued parameter as value
        DataTable allIds = new DataTable();
        allIds.Columns.Add("Id"); // Name of column need to be same as in created Type

        foreach(var id in guids)
            allids.Rows.Add(id);

        SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@AllIds",
            SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured // Important for table-valued parameters
            TypeName = "IdTableType", // Important! Name of the type must be provided
            Value = allIds
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(idParam);

        var documents = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                documents[guid] = reader[0].ToString();
            }               
        }

        return documents;
    }
}
```

You don't need to prepare the command any more. Besides after first execution next queries will use same compiled query plan, because query text remain same.

Comment: This method works great.  Performs very well with larger amounts of IDs as well (unlike an IN clause)

Comment: This looks great.  I'm trying to run it, but I get an exception that it needs an explicit type.  Setting idParam.SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured seems to fix it.  Does that sound correct?  This leads to an exception that variable length parameters needs a size.  I'm not sure whether I set this to the size of Guid or the size of number of items times Guid, but when I set that to a reasonably large number, that seems fine.  Lastly, "all" is a keyword so I changed it to a valid identifier in the query and it works great.  This is a great solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @cabird, you right about `SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured` need to be provided. Then about length: you don't need to use `command.Prepare` anymore, as I have mentioned in the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can bunch them into sets of ids and pass a table valued parameter into the query. With Dapper this looks a bit like:

```
connection.Query("select document from Documents where id in @ids", new { ids = guids});
```

**BEWARE** though theres an 8000 parameter limit in sql so you will need to batch up your reads.

btw.. I'd highly recommend looking at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) or another micro orm for this type of data access.